# PHP MySQL calculate how many rows have the same data

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, well I know I can just say WHERE example='vrvrv' but that's not the case.  Ok I have a rating system and whenever a page is rated the page id and the date it was rated is sent to a table in my database.  Now on the homepage I want to determine top rated that day, I can easily compare dates but I'm not quite sure how to count how many rows have the same value in the project_id column.  It would be amazing if someone could help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GROUP and COUNT to get duplicates:

```
SELECT count(`project_id`) AS `duplicates` FROM `table` GROUP BY `project_id` HAVING `duplicates` > 1
```

Comment: Wait, what exactly is id your selecting?

Comment: I just assumed an ID ... you can skip that